# Function isSpecialNumber(n) doesn't give the desired result

Tags: javascript

```js
function isSpecialNumber(n) {
  let str = n.toString();

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

    if (str.charAt(i) > 5) {
      return 'NOT!!'
    } else {
      return 'Special!!';
    }
  }

}

console.log(
  isSpecialNumber(144525),
  isSpecialNumber(2),
  isSpecialNumber(9),
  isSpecialNumber(23),
  isSpecialNumber(39)
)
```

How it have to work:

isSpecialNumber(2) === 'Special!!'
2 is a single digit in the interval [0:5].

isSpecialNumber(9) === 'NOT!!'
9 is a one-digit number, but it is not in the interval [0:5].

isSpecialNumber(23) === 'Special!!'
All digits of the number 23 are in the interval [0:5].

isSpecialNumber(39) === 'NOT!!'
The second digit (9) is not in the interval [0:5].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you need to do is put the return ¨Special¨ outside of the for. Like this:

```js
function isSpecialNumber(n) {
  let str = n.toString();

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str.charAt(i) > 5) {
      return "NOT!!";
    } 
  }
  return "Special!!"
}
```

Because in your solution if one of the numbers is smaller than 5 its returning "Special" and maybe the next one is not.

Comment: It might be worth adding a little explanation of why the original didn't work (always returning on the first iteration) and how this solves that issue, in addition to the code solution.

Comment: `if (+str.charAt(i) > 5)` to be sure

Comment: super, very short code, thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

```
function isSpecialNumber(n) {
  let str = n.toString();
  let found = 'special'; 

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

    if (str.charAt(i) > 5) {
      found =  'NOT!!';
    }
  }
  return found;

}

console.log(
  isSpecialNumber(144525),
  isSpecialNumber(2),
  isSpecialNumber(9),
  isSpecialNumber(23),
  isSpecialNumber(39)
)
```

Comment: If want to improve the efficiency you can return ¨NOT¨ once you find a non special number and then you don't need to loop over the other elements of the array

Comment: True, yours is better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's a little bit different but it should do the same:

```
function isSpecialNumber(n) {
  // n.toString() turns the number into a string
  // .split('') splits the string into an array
  // .every loops through the items in an array and
  // checks that all the elements return true for the function that
  // passed as the parameter into the every function.
  // .every doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every
  const special = n.toString()
    .split()
    .every((digit) => parseInt(digit) < 5)

  // You can also do this, which uses .some
  // .some doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some
  /*
  const special = n.toString()
    .split()
    .some((digit) => parseInt(digit) > 5)
  */
  
  // if all the digits are less than 5, then it's special
  // and should return "Special!!"
  // else, return "NOT!!"
  return special ? "Special!!" : "NOT!!"
}

console.log(
  isSpecialNumber(144525),
  isSpecialNumber(2),
  isSpecialNumber(9),
  isSpecialNumber(23),
  isSpecialNumber(39)
)
```

Comment: thanks, but a little complicated for me, but trying to understand..

Answer (score -1):

generally i think that the problem stands on the way you compare the supposed numbers. You are writing str.charAt(i) > 5 but i think you forgot that you turned the number into a string first , so you are comparing the ascii value of the character with the number which is not going to give the appropriate result. I suggest that you parse the character to integer first and the compare with 5.
Example :       parseInt(str.charAt(i)) > 5

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).